# Jest, NestJS, TypeORM End To End Testing

Tags: jestjs, linker-errors, nestjs, e2e-testing, typeorm

In the NestJS tutorial E2E tests are set up with their single example module imported.
This pattern does not seem to work in an application with more complex relations between the typeORM entities. After extensively checking that there were [no inconsistencies in import statements](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/420) and no missing [`TypeOrmModule.forFeature()`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/420#issuecomment-611474412) in the relevant files, I gave up and simply imported my entire `AppModule` (root module for my application -- same as NestJS default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short if you are seeing of the form

```
Error: Entity metadata for EntityA#entityB was not found. 
Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.
```

You can try importing all the related modules or simply import your entire application.